# load behavior of azure configuration files - serviceconfiguration.csdef, serviceconfiguration.cloud.cscfg

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

In terms of loading and reading do serviceconfiguration.csdef, serviceconfiguration.cloud.cscfg behave the same way as web.config?

According to MSDN the settings in web.config are "calculated once and then cached across subsequent requests. ASP.NET automatically watches for file changes and re-computes the cache when any of the configuration files change within that file's hierarchy." Is this behavior similar for the csdef and cscfg files as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is similar but at a higher level.  If you make a change to the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file from the portal, the instances will restart to have the updated settings.  Take a look at this for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh472157.aspx